# Is there a tool to find the action of an enzyme in a metabolic pathway?

Tags: bioinformatics, enzymes

Is there any tool to search the biochemical action of a particular enzyme in a metabolic pathway of an organism? In other words, how can I find if enzyme "E"  is involved in the metabolic pathway for organism "X".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the KEGG pathway database may be of some use to you.

Link is here: http://www.genome.jp/kegg/pathway.html

This a database of manually drawn pathway maps, I have used the site myself and it is very useful in determining if your enzyme is in a pathway and where it lies in it. This is assuming though, your enzyme is in the database and has been mapped.